# Building horizontal slider - divs floating vertically

Tags: html, css, clearfix

I am trying to build simple horizontal image slider with overflow:hidden and floating divs. Hovewer, I am not able to float them horizontally - they always appear in vertical order. I tried many examples from the web, hovewer I still don't know where I am wrong.

**HTML:**

```
<div id="slidingWindow">
    <div class="slidingSection clearfix">Something something</div>
    <div class="slidingSection clearfix">Again something</div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#slidingWindow {
overflow:hidden;
width: 470px;
height: 500px;
background-color: red;
}

.slidingSection {
margin: 5px;
background-color: green;
width: 470px;
height: 400px;
float: left;
}

.clearfix:after { 
content: "."; 
visibility: hidden; 
display: block; 
height: 0; 
clear: both;
}
```

This JSFiddle contains simplest example of my problem:
http://jsfiddle.net/v4udd47t/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your support is IE10+ and are not concerned with Opera Mini, then you can use `display: flex`. That way you don't need any extra markup or even floats and clearfix.

Along with using `flex` you will also have to set a `min-width` on the slides that is equal to the container minus any margins and padding. In regards to margins and padding, the container will also have to accommodate any that are applied to the slides (I noticed you have a 5px margin on them).

**HTML:**

```
<div id="slidingWindow">
    <div class="slidingSection clearfix">Something something</div>
    <div class="slidingSection clearfix">Again something</div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#slidingWindow {
    overflow:hidden;
    width: 480px; /* width of slide + left and right margins */
    height: 500px;
    background-color: red;
    display: -ms-flex;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
}

.slidingSection {
    margin: 5px;
    background-color: green;
    width: 470px;
    min-width: 470px; /* required */
    height: 400px;
}
```

Below is a fork of your fiddle with the size reduced and having an animation on hover to show it is working properly:

```css
#slidingWindow {
 overflow:hidden;
    width: 260px;
    height: 300px;
    background-color: red;
    display: -ms-flex;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
}

.slidingSection {
    margin: 5px;
    background-color: green;
 width: 250px;
    min-width: 250px;
 height: 200px;
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 750ms;
 transition: transform 750ms;
}

#slidingWindow:hover > .slidingSection {
    -webkit-transform: -webkit-translate3d(-260px, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(-260px, 0, 0);
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 750ms;
    transition: transform 750ms;
}
```

```html
<div id="slidingWindow">
    <div class="slidingSection">Something something</div>
    <div class="slidingSection">Again something</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because you need to Wrap the individual sliders in another div that has a width = number of slides*width. I updated your example here, and made the overflow: scroll so you can see the difference http://jsfiddle.net/v4udd47t/1/

```
<div id="slidingWindow">
    <div class="slider-container">
        <div class="slidingSection clearfix">Something something</div>
        <div class="slidingSection clearfix">Again something</div>
    </div>
</div>


.slider-container {
    width: 1000px;    
}
```

to set the width dynamically you can do this

```
var number_of_slides = $(".slidingSection").length;

$(".slider-container").css('width', number_of_slides * 470 + "px");
```

Comment: Is it possible to create wrapper div that doesn't have decalred width in css? E.g. when number of images is dynamic and I would like to rely only on number of divs inside wrapper div?

Comment: You can do it using Jquery like this


    var number_of_slides = $(".slidingSection").length + 1;
    $(".slider-container").css('width', number_of_slides * 470 + "px");

http://jsfiddle.net/v4udd47t/2/

I also updated the answer with the adjustments